# What is wrong with my prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, syntax-error, prepared-statement

I have an error in my SQL syntax when using prepared statements which i can't seem to track down. I have simplified the code considerably but the error persists. This is my first go at prepared statements so it may be something fairly basic but google-ing still didn't help me. What I want to do is update a table with a set of parameters which I hand over in variables (in the given example I substituted this set of parameters by a simple "4" (not in a variable) and only hand over the parameter choosing the row as variable). The code goes like this:

```
SQLcommand.CommandText = "PREPARE my_prep_statement FROM 'UPDATE tbl1 SET status = 4 WHERE Number =  ?';"
SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DosiNr", "123")
SQLcommand.CommandText = "EXECUTE my_prep_statement USING @DosiNr;"
SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The column Number is of type varchar(8).
The error message goes "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''123'' at line 1" and the updating of my table doesn't happen.

I am working with a mySQL database, server version 5.1.41

I have the strong feeling of failing to see something very simple here, but i need help spotting it :-(

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You mention an error but don't make clear what the error *is*. Are you getting an exception? If so, what message is being shown? If not, what *does* happen? Also, please add a tag for the specific SQL database product you're working against.

Comment: oh sorry! i updated my question - hoping it is clear now?

Comment: Provide **complete and unchanged** error message text, not a tale about it.

Comment: I only ommitted the part where i was told to check my manual but i see how it is cconfusing to post incomplete error messages, i fixed that in my post.

Comment: However, substituting the `?`with `@DosiNr`in the prepared statement results in exactly the same error message. Also, writing the value '123' instead of `@DosiNr`in the execute statement gives that same error message. If the `?`in the prepared statement is not a wildcard (that can also be used for user variables such as `@DosiNr`) then I have to go back to learning the basics of prepared statements - please tell me if that's what i have to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using prepared statements from an API you don't use the SQL `PREPARE` syntax but a specific API function. For .Net, it is `SqlCommand.Prepare`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) provides a pretty good example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rveerd, working with .Prepare solved my issue!! :) wouldn't have gotten there on my own!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide the literal as prepared statement parameter, only UDV is allowed, see [EXECUTE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html). Set your value to user-defined variable then execute the statement using this variable.
In SQL it looks like

```sql
PREPARE my_prep_statement FROM 'UPDATE tbl1 SET status = 4 WHERE Number =  ?';
SET @var := 123;
EXECUTE my_prep_statement USING @var;
```

so you need something like

```py
SQLcommand.CommandText = "PREPARE my_prep_statement FROM 'UPDATE tbl1 SET status = 4 WHERE Number =  ?';"
SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLcommand.CommandText = "SET @var := @DosiNr;"
SQLcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DosiNr", "123")
SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
SQLcommand.CommandText = "EXECUTE my_prep_statement USING @var;"
SQLcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It is possible that `@var` will be treated by VB.Net as query parameter which' value is not set, with according error... if so I don't know what to do with this problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that i've been ignoring the difference between UDVs and parameters! However, the command `SET @var := @DosiNr;` throws back a fatal error "Fatal error encountered during command execution"

Comment: ...the same happens when i do the `.parameters.addwithvalue("@DosiNr", "123")` before `SET @var := @DosiNr`

Comment: okay so now i found the inner exception. it says "parameter '@var' must be defined". I feel like I'm going in circles. Do you have any more ideas about this, Akina?

Comment: @sarah Please read the last sentence of my answer. PS. I know that this problem can be solved... try to search SO by error message text and VB tag.

Comment: Thank you, Akina! :) (I read that sentence but was still hoping for mysql, not vb, to cause that exception)